# Gitlab ci - differences in artifacts app jar

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab-ci

My dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u201-jdk-alpine3.9
ADD target/app-snapshot-0.0.1.jar .
```

In gitlab-ci runner, during maven building process:

```
maven:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: maven

    script:
        - "mvn clean package -e"
      artifacts:
        name: "app-snapshot"
        paths:
          - ./target/app-snapshot-0.0.1.jar
    
    build:
      stage: build
      script:
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
        - BUILD_IMAGE_NAME=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:`echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" | tr /# _`
        - docker build --pull --force-rm=true -t "$BUILD_IMAGE_NAME" .
        - docker push "$BUILD_IMAGE_NAME"
```

But, when I used docker image after commits, changes etc., still I see first application .jar, without changes.

Where is my mistake? I would like to see - after building process - all my changes in artifacts jar app.

Comment: I didn't understand all your problem but I think you have a cache issue. Maybe, (I say maybe) the `artifacts` instruction cached your previous .jar.

Comment: The problem is: after building process, when I use docker image - I see first version of my application - no changes, updates etc.

Comment: When do you build your docker image?

Comment: In gitlab-ci file, during building process. Please check my original post - was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem, but have some ways to "solve":

1. Try to fix the indentation:

```
maven:
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: maven
  script:
    - "mvn clean package -e"
  artifacts:
    name: "app-snapshot"
    paths:
      - ./target/app-snapshot-0.0.1.jar
```

2. Use patterns in artifacts: (It is good for when versions change you not need to change the code)

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
  artifacts:
    name: "app-snapshot"
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8u201-jdk-alpine3.9
ADD target/*.jar .
```

3. Use `dependencies` [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies):

   In you build job define dependencies from maven:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - BUILD_IMAGE_NAME=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:`echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" | tr /# _`
    - docker build --pull --force-rm=true -t "$BUILD_IMAGE_NAME" .
    - docker push "$BUILD_IMAGE_NAME"
  dependencies:
    - maven
```

4. Is a good practice use `artifacts:expire` [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexpire_in)

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
  artifacts:
    name: "app-snapshot"
    expire_in: 15 min #Just a example
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It helps me to clear some code in my project.