# How to save jar files as gitlab artifacts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to get the files generated by maven to store as artifacts. To my understanding I have edited the following ci yml.

```
    stages:
  - build
  - package

maven-build:
    stage: build
    script:
     - mvn install
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - art/
   
maven-package:
    stage: package
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - art/
    script:
     -  mvn package -U
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699920/gitlab-ci-differences-in-artifacts-app-jar refer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, maven will build artifacts to a directory called `target`. You are not including this path in your artifacts declaration.

To deal with this you can:

1. Add `target` to your `paths:` array in your yaml **OR**
2. Add a script step to move/copy the `target` directory to the `./art` which you already include in your `paths:` array **OR**
3. Change the directory to which Maven will place built files.